# Aggregation based on another column values

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have the following table:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Product_id | customer_id |
+------------+-------------+
| a          | c1          |
| a          | c2          |
| a          | c3          |
| a          | c4          |
| b          | c1          |
| c          | c1          |
| b          | c2          |
| d          | c2          |
+------------+-------------+
```

I want to find the number of (a, b, c) products purchases per customer and the number of (a, b, d) products purchases per customer. I tried to use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` but I only managed to the find the number purchases of each customers [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e26c5/26/0). Do I need to use `CASE WHEN` or `DECODE`? How can I achieve that?

The expected output is something like:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | ABC_PRODUCT | ABD_PRODUCT |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| c1          |           1 |           0 |
| c2          |           0 |           1 |
| c3          |           0 |           0 |
| c4          |           0 |           0 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single aggregation and no subqueries.  The key is using a nested case statement with aggregation to count each product for each customer.  The following determines whether a customer has each "bundle":

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
       (case when max(case when product_id = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  max(case when product_id = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  max(case when product_id = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) = 3
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as ABC,
       (case when max(case when product_id = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  max(case when product_id = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  max(case when product_id = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) = 3
             then 1
             else 0
        end) as ABD           
FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Now, your question is actually about the number of such purchases.  So, I suppose a customer could purchase each item twice, and you would want them counted twice.  If so, then the number is the *least* value of any counts.  You can get this as well:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
       least(sum(case when product_id = 'a' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when product_id = 'b' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when product_id = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) 
            ) as ABC,
       least(sum(case when product_id = 'a' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when product_id = 'b' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when product_id = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) 
            ) as ABD
FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: The second script is exactly what I want. I had trouble articulating my question. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query to find customer having the products `a, b and c`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('a', 'b', 'c') 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3
```

**To get the count try**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
  SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('a', 'b', 'd')
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3
)x
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post with my expected outcome

Comment: The second script is promising. I think I need to amend it to take two cases (a,b,c) and (a,b,d) and add customer_id column

Answer (score 0):

Based entirely off @TechDo's example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID, 
       DECODE((SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
                 FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES CS2
                WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
                  AND CS2.CUSTOMER_ID = CS.CUSTOMER_ID
               GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3), NULL, 0, 1) AS ABC_PRODUCT,
       DECODE((SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
                 FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES CS2
                WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('A', 'B', 'D') 
                  AND CS2.CUSTOMER_ID = CS.CUSTOMER_ID
               GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3), NULL, 0, 1) AS ABD_PRODUCT
  FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES CS
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post with my expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS_SALES.CUSTOMER_ID,NVL(MAX(abc.CUSTOMER_ID),0) as ABC_PRODUCT ,NVL(MAX(abd.CUSTOMER_ID),0) as ABD_PRODUCT  FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES 
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
  FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('a', 'b', 'd')
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3) abd
ON abd.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMERS_SALES.CUSTOMER_ID
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
  FROM CUSTOMERS_SALES
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID)=3) abc
ON abc.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMERS_SALES.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS_SALES.CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS_SALES.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e26c5/150)